# Unknown DLL files Windows 8.1 64 bit

Tags: dll

Some programs seem to have missing DLL files but even with manual downloading of the files after that an entry point error occurs. After using Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com) for the exe files more missing DLL files where found and downloaded except these two.

API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL

EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL

No idea where to find these files so my question is, are they obsolete or is it possible to rename other DLL files to bypass this issue?

Comment: Depends has not been updated in a very long time.  The author basically gave up trying to keep up with innovations in the OS loader.  It can't properly handle manifests nor these [MinWin forwarders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinWin).  Easy to recognize from Lx-y-z.DLL in their name.  They are not always files, so you can't really know whether it is a problem.  Usually it is not.  The proper way to do this is to use [loader snaps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps).  Requires a debugger, end-users might get help from SysInternals' ProcMon.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, much appreciated. I might use that next time but for now all seems to work without those two files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the file ext-ms-win-ntuser-uicontext-ext-l1-1-0.dll ?

It seems this file might have been included in some early version of Win 8, but is no longer included in updated Win 8, or Win 8.1 and later.

Some users report this issue solved after installing / repairing "Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio" relevant to the error message that you get. If you are unsure, please contact dll-files.com support.

"Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio" are available at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003 (If using a 64bit (x64) version of Windows, install both vcredist_x64.exe and vcredist_x86.exe versions).

Comment: I already installed the packages but the programs only worked after using Dependency Walker to get a full list, still somehow these two keep coming up but they don't pose a problem for running the exe file.